# Interesting Differential equation problem $x\frac{dy}{dx} + 3\frac{dx}{dy} = y^2 $.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation to get $y $ as a function of $x$.

> $$x\frac{dy}{dx} + 3\frac{dx}{dy} = y^2$$

I tried taking $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ to be $p$ . Then proceed to factorise the expression but nothing happened. Please help me in this question as I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We change the role of $x$ and $y$, therfore
$$y\dfrac{dx}{dy}+3\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x^2$$
gives the equation
$$x^2y'-3y'^2=y$$
which has two following roots
$$y'=\dfrac{-x^2\pm\sqrt{x^4-12y}}{-6}$$
now let $z^2=x^4-12y$ which leads us to DE
$$(2x^3-x^2+z)dx-zdz=0$$
that could be convert to an exact equation with $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial z}=1$ and $\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}=0$ (with standard notation). After solve that and substitution, exchange the previous role of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the method. Nice approach.

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't solve it completely!